# PhoneGap - Updating a contact email address

Tags: cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to do some basic contact browsing/editing.  I'm able to update the contact's name information and provide an email, but each time I do, it appends the email as an additional email address, instead of editing the existing one or replacing all emails on the contact with the newly provided ones.

How do you update a particular email address on a contact?

Currently my code is split out among several functions, but it basically looks like this:

```
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create();

var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = "John";
name.familyName = "Doe"; 

var emails = [];
emails[0] = new ContactField('work', 'john.doe@test.com', true);

myContact.id = 12345;  // Update contact 12345
myContact.emails = emails;
myContact.name = name;

myContact.save(successCB, failCB);
```

For whatever reason, this always appends an additional "work" email address to the contact, rather than overwrite what is already there..

Comment: What code do you currently have?  It's a lot easier to suggest a modification than give you everything.

Comment: I updated the post with consolidated sample code.

Comment: The Contact.id property should be a DOMString, have you tried using a string?

Comment: Yes.  In real code, I'm actually setting it to $("email").val(), so it is being set as a string.  The contact is properly reflecting name changes, but it is gaining the new email address as an appended value each time, instead of clearing out old addresses or simply updating an address of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by first reloading the contact I want to update.  If the existing contact already has the email address I want to save, I skip saving that address.

I still don't know how to remove an email address from a contact, however.  So far everything is acting as if email addresses can only be added to an existing contact.